# how to design a rheostat which gives me fix 24V supply for different input of 24V,48V,110V,220V

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, resistance

i want a constant voltage output using rheostat. It can be any electronic circuit control or by appropriate tapping.

Comment: Have you had any ideas so far other than maybe thinking EE is a free design service?

Comment: What does the rheostat have to do with it?

Comment: I want to provide a constant voltage input to my auxilliary supply coil for different input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the idea that this can be accomplished with a rheostat.

Your requirements are directing toward your needing to use a wide range input switching voltage regulator. The regulator you choose may very well have to be a buck-boost type if you do indeed require an 24V input to 24V output. If you dropped that requirement then a buck switching regulator could give you your 24V output over the range of inputs from say 36V to 220V.

I am assuming that you are calling out DC input and output voltages here. If you are talking about AC voltages here then you are more likely going to want a transformer with a multi tapped primary and a selector switch to select the primary tap based upon the inpu voltage present. If that is the case make sure to carefully make the proper selection of the tap before before applying any power to the circuit.

Comment: Do you got any idea which company provides such buck converter? because i tried looking but found none of the buck converter having supply range higher then 60V

Comment: This site is not here to help you find suitable products for your application.